# Voltage drop across 3Quadrant triac

Tags: triac

I am going to start off with the disclaimer that I have a Software Engineering background and very little electrical engineering background.

I am using a 3q triac on a breadboard circuit. My gate current/voltage is supplied by a a 9VDC battery. The circuit I am using is more or less represented here:

[image: Schematic]

When I use a 3q triac, my load is getting about 5/6th of the voltage. The rest is dissipating across the triac. The waveform is chopped off/flatted above a certain voltage and becomes sinosidal again below it.

When I use a 4q triac, I don't face this issue.

The 3q triac I have been using in the circuit is T405-800B-TR whereas the 4q triac I tried is BT138-800,127.

Is this normal for 3q triacs to eat up some of the Voltage or is there something wrong with this particular triac that I am using?

Comment: A 3 quadrant TRIAC is designed to NOT trigger at all in the 3rd quadrant and that's the one you are trying to use it in. This is intended to prevent false triggering which occurs in inductive load circuits where current and voltage are well out of phase. Many std TRICS are somewhat less sensitive in the 3rd quadrant as a natural feature of how they are constructed.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon ?? The T405-800B-TR are specified for quadrants I, II and III, but not IV. http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00002383.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should flip the battery around and drive the gate with -V with a 3-quadrant triac.

That will use quadrants II and III.

[image]

The T405-800B-TR is not guaranteed to trigger in quadrant IV at all, so it's not at all surprising that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Is the quadrant definition somehow different than the [mathematic](http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/38/graphing-quadrants.jpg) one?

Comment: @sherrellbc They're just quadrants in a 2D space. If you plot MT2 voltage on the Y axis (positive up, as usual), and gate voltage on the X axis (positive to the right, as usual), the quadrant numbering is the same as your link (though I wouldn't have been surprised if it wasn't).

Comment: Ah yes. I should have actually looked at the values rather than the quadrant enumeration.

Comment: Thanks Spehro. I always knew that the 3q quadrants had different triggering specifications than 4q but I never put too much time into trying to understand them. Your answer helped me immensely and saved me a lot of time. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If the 'scope is AC coupled, then 'certain voltage' != 0.

Answer (score 0):

With any junction device there is a threshold voltage that is required to exist across the terminals in order for sufficient energy to carry electrons across the depletion region. So in short, yes. Note that if you increase the voltage applied to the device that the `forward voltage` will not increase proportionally.

Comment: That's not an especially useful answer in this case. A 3 quadrant TRIAC is designed to NOT trigger at all in the quadrant it as being used in. This is intended to prevent false triggering which occurs in inductive load circuits where current and voltage are well out of phase.